# printing problems

Tags: printing

My 3 digit HP printer finally gave up on me so I bought a new one and then the fun started.
When I bought the old one I plugged it in and it just worked. Til now. I'll skip over the several new ones I've tried. That's for another day. The last one I got is a Brother HL-L2350DW which won't "install" in my 20.04. I follow the how to instructions (as all the others) and can't find the next step. Frustrating. I know it's me not knowing computing
skills but this has me baffeled. What am I missing?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post those instructions.

Comment: What you want is at https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSDriverlessPrinting. Knowing whether the connection is USB or network would help. Or does it matter?

Comment: Finally found (in b